# Odd DB Exception

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

We have been wrestling with an odd exception and have yet to find resolution.

At what appears to be random times, our application will throw an exception with the messages of the last two inner exceptions always being "The underlying provider failed on Open" and Login failed for user '*userName*'.

I have seen the last of these exceptions (the one that reports that the login failed) before but have never encountered the other.  As such, I am not sure I understand what is happening.

Once this exception is encountered, it seems as though it *fixes* itself shortly after.  By this, I mean that if you try to access anything in the application shortly after the exception is first thrown you will continue to get the same or similar exceptions.  However, if you wait a few minutes, everything in the application works as expected.

Some other things that I feel are worth mentioning:

1. This seems to happen when using a SQL Azure database.  We have
   contacted Microsoft to see if they can help us determine what is
   happening.  They have been able to tell us that an invalid password
   is being sent but cannot tell us what it is (blank or otherwise).\
2. It seems as though references to Entity Framework are sprinkled
   throughout the stack traces of every instance of these exceptions.
3. We have Application Insights turned on so there seems to be a ton of
   information available...we are not quite sure how to decipher all of
   it at the moment.
4. We are certain that the login information is correct as we have verified that the connection string is correct and that application features (that access the database) all work except when receiving these exceptions.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as we have grown quite desperate to solve this issue.

Comment: Is it possible you're sending an old password and then retrying with a different one?

Comment: @james5 - I don't believe so.  We have an object that stores the connection string and this object is injected into every service object that makes a DB connection (creates the EF DbContext object).

Comment: "Failed on open" and "Login failed" both occured for me (on SQL Express) when the targeted database does not exist, yet is queried already. Which initializer do you use for your DbContext?

Comment: Can you try the steps provided in this troubleshooting guide when the error "The underlying provider failed on open" happens and let us know how it goes? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to initialize the DBContext with the following piece of code?

```
using (DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    context.Connection.Open();
    // the rest
}
```

Some more recommendations. Make sure the connection string has a timeout of 30 as shown below.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

A retry logic should be added to your application to be able to face transient errors as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling) because you say after a few minutes the issue goes away. An example of a retry logic is:

```
public void HandleTransients()
{
    var connStr = "some database";
    var _policy = RetryPolicy.Create < SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy(
        retryCount: 3,
        retryInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    using (var conn = new ReliableSqlConnection(connStr, _policy))
    {
        // Do SQL stuff here.
    }
}
```

f